# Deleting content of XML element in Inno Setup

Tags: xml, powershell, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to convert a PowerShell script to Inno Setup Pascal Script code.

```powershell
$regularExpression=@'
(?ms)^(\s*  <ReportParametersLayout>\s*?\r?\n).*?\r?\n(\s*  </ReportParametersLayout>\s*)
'@

Foreach ($file in $files) {
    $text = (Get-Content $file) | Out-String 
    $text -replace $regularExpression, '$1$2' | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $file
}
```

This part of PowerShell script deletes content between `ReportParametersLayout` element of RDL file with regular expressions for converting SQL Server 2016 Reports to SQL Server 2008.

```xml
<Report>
  ...
  <ReportParametersLayout>
    <GridLayoutDefinition>
      <NumberOfColumns>4</NumberOfColumns>
      <NumberOfRows>3</NumberOfRows>
      <CellDefinitions>
        <CellDefinition>
          <ColumnIndex>0</ColumnIndex>
          <RowIndex>0</RowIndex>
          <ParameterName>StartDate</ParameterName>
        </CellDefinition>
        <CellDefinition>
          <ColumnIndex>1</ColumnIndex>
          <RowIndex>0</RowIndex>
          <ParameterName>EndDate</ParameterName>
        </CellDefinition>
      </CellDefinitions>
    </GridLayoutDefinition>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  ...
<Report>
```

What should I do for deleting content between XML element of `ReportParametersLayout` to reach this outcome in Code Section?

```xml
<Report>
  ...
  <ReportParametersLayout>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  ...
</Report>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will delete nodes selected by XPath:

```pascal
procedure DeleteNodes(FileName, Path: string);
var
  XMLDocument: Variant;
  XMLNodeList: Variant;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(FileName);
    if XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
    begin
      MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' +
        XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
    end
      else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLNodeList := XMLDocument.selectNodes(Path);
      for Index := 0 to XMLNodeList.length - 1 do
      begin
        XMLNodeList.item[Index].parentNode.removeChild(XMLNodeList.item[Index]);
      end;
      XMLDocument.save(FileName);
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

You can use the function like this to delete all child nodes of all `<ReportParametersLayout>` tags:

```pascal
DeleteNodes('C:\some\path\my.xml', '//ReportParametersLayout/*');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this solution. This was actual solution that i was looking :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't work out exactly what your regex is doing, but you can clear the content of an xml element very easily if you parse it with a proper xml parser rather than a regex:

```bsh
PS> $xml = [xml] @"
<ReportParametersLayout>
  <GridLayoutDefinition>
    <NumberOfColumns>4</NumberOfColumns>
    <NumberOfRows>3</NumberOfRows>
    <CellDefinitions>
      <CellDefinition>
        <ColumnIndex>0</ColumnIndex>
        <RowIndex>0</RowIndex>
        <ParameterName>StartDate</ParameterName>
      </CellDefinition>
      <CellDefinition>
        <ColumnIndex>1</ColumnIndex>
        <RowIndex>0</RowIndex>
        <ParameterName>EndDate</ParameterName>
      </CellDefinition>
    </CellDefinitions>
  </GridLayoutDefinition>
</ReportParametersLayout>
"@;

PS> $xml.DocumentElement.OuterXml # just to show the 'before' value
<ReportParametersLayout><GridLayoutDefinition><NumberOfColumns> ... etc ...

PS> $xml.DocumentElement.InnerText = "";

PS> $xml.DocumentElement.OuterXml
<ReportParametersLayout></ReportParametersLayout>
```

If you're doing any other modifications to your xml I'd suggest you avoid regex for the sake of your future sanity if you ever have to come back to it to make changes :-).

Comment: @nedensel You wrote that you were looking for Inno Setup solution. This is still PowerShell.

Comment: Hi, I thanked him because of his help. Sorry to forgot mentioning this was not the solution that i was looking.